# Calculate weekdays with Date functions

Tags: excel, vba, date

Below is my SQL code to calculate the weekdays for the report. I am trying to get the same result with VBA Excel.

```
set @end_date = DATEADD(DD,-DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())+1,GETDATE())
set @begin_date = DATEADD(DD,-6,@end_date)
```

I tried this:

```
endDate = DateAdd("D", -DatePart("W", DateValue(Now)) + 1, "DateValue(Now)")
startDate = DateAdd("D", -6, "endDate")
```

However I can't get the result!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the same output if i added parenthesis after `Now` and remove the quotes from the last input of the `DateAdd` function and the endDate variable. The quotes make the code think you are passing in a string instead of a function or variable.

So your VBA would look like:

`endDate = DateAdd("D", -DatePart("W", DateValue(Now())) + 1, DateValue(Now()))`

`startDate = DateAdd("D", -6, endDate)`

Comment: Please mark as the answer if this solved you question.